# Notify User when server time equal column value in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 for reservation. And I am developing an application using C#.

I need to warn the user (show notification icon in taskbar) when the time of the Windows clock is less than the value of the column `ReservationDate` by 30 mins.

I know that I can do this using a timer with an interval for example 1 min.

But is there a better way without the timer?

Comment: Does the data in the table (in the database) change very often?  If not, pull it down once and do everything in the C# code

Answer (score 0):

You can have background windows service which polls the database once a minute to check, if there are any reservations within 30 minutes and throw a popup.

I have given sample code below for reference. The logic can be encapsulated in a procedure and called once a minute.

- If the procedure returns 1, then there are some reservations within 30 minutes.
- If the procedure returns 0, then there are no reservations within 30 minutes.

```sql
DECLARE @reservation table(ReservationTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @reservation
VALUES ('2020-08-28 11:00:00.000')

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @reservation
WHERE DATEDIFF(mm,ReservationTime, getdate()) <= 30)
BEGIN

SELECT 1; -- return in the case of stored procedure 

END
ELSE
BEGIN

SELECT 0; -- return in the case of stored procedure

END
```